# Does Death's Presence check base power or actual power of a creature?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have [Death's Presence](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Death%27s%20Presence) on the field, which says

> Whenever a creature you control dies, put X +1/+1 counters on target creature you control, where X is the power of the creature that died.

...and a creature I control with base power toughness 0/0 and 4 +1/+1 counters on it dies, do those counters then move because of Death's Presence, or does Death's Presence only take into account the base power?

Answer (score 6):

The counters don't technically move¹, but **the same amount of counters are put on another creature.**

When cards mention power without explicitly mentioning "base power", it always means the actual power of the creature, taking into account all +1/+1 counters, static buffs, and of course base power (the same is true for toughness respectively, of course).

This is also indicated in [Death's Presence](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Death%27s%20Presence)'s oracle text:

> X is the power of that creature as it last existed on the battlefield.

---

¹ The reason I mention that counters don't technically move is that for a 2/2 creature with two +1/+1 counters, you'd still place four counters on the target creature with Death's Presence, not two - phrasing it as "moving counters" might be confusing in this regard. There are cards in magic that actually move counters, such as [Bioshift](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bioshift), and in case of this example creature, they would only put two counters on the target creature.

Comment: Another way in way in which the move/create distinction matters is if it were "move", then it wouldn't be as clear as to whether it counts for Doubling Season.